# Plotly. How to remove surfaces XZ, YZ in Mesh3d figure?

Tags: python, 3d, plotly, figure

I'm trying to generate a paraboloid.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

x = [-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
y = [-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
x, y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
x = x.flatten()
y = y.flatten()

z = x * x + y * y

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Mesh3d(x=y, y=x, z=z)])
fig.show()
```

There is what i get:

[image: screenshot].

How to remove these two blue surfaces XZ, YZ?

Answer (score 1):

@derek-o Yes I think you're right. Your solution looks fine. I also added another statements to remove color gradient and scale bar

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

x = [-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
y = [-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
z = []
for i in range(0,len(x)):
    z.append([x[i] * x[i] + j * j for j in y])

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Surface(
    x=x,
    y=y,
    z=z,
    showscale=False,
    colorscale=[[0, 'rgb(0,0,255)'], [1, 'rgb(0,0,255)']]
    )])
```

It works well

[image]

Comment: If my answer was helpful, you can consider [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer#:~:text=It%20simply%20means%20that%20the,answer%20corresponds%20to%20reputation%20gains.), or accept your own answer which is pretty similar except for the formatting. Either way, it'll be helpful to people with a similar question as you if they see that this question has been answered, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, a 3D mesh plot connects the vertices with triangles, so there is probably a triangle being drawn between the beginning and ending vertices.

You could instead use a surface to draw a paraboloid, as suggested by @empet in a [Plotly forum post](https://community.plotly.com/t/3d-surface-plotly-hardest-library-for-python-from-user-pov-spent-3-hours-on-trying-to-understand-3d-surface-no-progress/7849/2) on drawing 3D surfaces.

```
x = np.linspace(-6,6,100)
y = np.linspace(-6,6,100)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
Z = X**2+Y**2 # z has the shape (100,100)
surf=dict(type='surface',
           x=x, 
           y=y,
           z=Z             
)
fig = go.Figure(surf)
```

[image]